# How to detect an end of byte[] message send through socket

Tags: c#, sockets

Let's assume that `_sslStream` is an established `SslStream` connection on client side.

```
private void DoStuff(string message)
{
   _streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_sslStream) { AutoFlush = true };
   _streamWriter.Write(GetGzipBytes("hello world"));
}

private static byte[] GetGzipBytes(string message)
{
    //Not a final implementation. Cannot add string "<EOF>" mark
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
}
```

How can I detect on server side that the received bytes are complete?

Is there some recommended "end of byte array" mark that I should add to the end of the array?

How do I make sure that the `GetGzipBytes()` method doesn't produce a `byte[]` that would have those bytes inside the message?

In case of string I would call:

```
_streamReader.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For binary messages there's no way to do it. You need to either know the number on bytes transmitted in advance or you need to add a defined end of message indicator.

Comment: To expand slightly on this answer, you have two choices. One is to make it into a message, where, for instance, you first send the number of bytes and then the Zip bytes. The other is to close the stream using `Close`; of course, using this second method you cannot send more than one 'message' per connection.

Answer (score -1):

Just call _streamWriter.End() - it will end current network stream and send to client. That's it.

Please note - it will not pass in your code example since your stream is not network stream.

You can use _stream.BinaryWrite(byteArray) to write byte array. For network streams.

Comment: There is no method .End() on StreamWriter class

Comment: You probably mean the `Close` method.

Comment: @VojtechB I meant End() or Close() methods in case of using NETWORK STREAM, not just for StreamWriter. I have mentioned this before. Example: Response.BinaryWrite(bytearray); Response.Close();